# Wpf Textbox text live input validation for decimal number in increments of 0.25 using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating a custom NumericUpDown control for WPF and need to validate the user entry into the text box.  I am not sure if the TextChanged event is the correct place to do this, but that's what I'm working with for now.

The TextChanged event occurs after every key press, so I have to check to make sure that each number conforms to the parameters.

My minimums, maximums, and increments vary, but they are all very similar to this:

```
Minimum = 4400
Maximum = 5850
Increment = 0.25
```

I'm trying to figure out a regex that will make sure that any digits following the decimal are `00` `25` `50` `75` and also the beginning of these number, 0, 2, 5, or 7.

Here is the regex I currently have, but it is disregarding digits typed after the decimal.

```
(\d+)(\.*)(0|2|5|7|00|25|50|75)*
```

So if I type the number 4254.3, `Match` returns success with the value `4254.`  What is missing from the regex?

Comment: try this:
^(\d+)(\.(00255075))?$

Comment: That's doesn't work.  It won't match `4545.` which is what the user will type before typing the final two digits.

Comment: This question is about **live input validation**, not about the *final input on-submit* validation. Solutions like `^(?:[1-9]|[1-9]?\.(?:25|50|75))$` or `^[1-9](?:\.25|\.50|\.75|)$` or `^(|[1-9])\.(25|50|75)$` do not work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d+(?:\.(?:[05]0?|[27]5?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OtFJvn/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.(?:[05]0?|[27]5?)?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?:[05]0?|[27]5?)?` - an optional sequence of

    - `[05]0?` - `0` or `5` and then an optional `0`
    - `|` - or
    - `[27]` - `2` or `7` and then
    - `5?` - an optional `5?`
- `$`  - end of string.